# using sheet index instead of name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

I would like to copy some contents from my first sheet, paste them into a new sheet, then delete the first sheet and rename the new (only) sheet to Sheet1.  But I never know what the second sheet will be named when I create it.  Most of the time, it will be Sheet2, but I can't count on it.  Here is the code taken just from creating a macro that does it, but it is using the sheet names as they were created in this instance.  I want to use the index of the sheets instead but don't know the syntax:

```
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Sheet1"
```

So where is says "Sheet2"...how do I make that so it's using the second sheet, not necessarily the sheet named Sheet2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Worksheets(2)` is the way to refer to the second sheet.

`Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` to the last one.

Try it like this:

```
Debug.Print Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).name
```

Comment: So in the above example, replace all "Sheet2" with Worksheets(2)?

Comment: @12fretter - yes

Comment: I'm back with a renewed question, same topic.  I have a new workbook, with this in one cell:

='[Daily Customer Count.xlsx]Mar 18'!$G$3

Where Mar 18 is the name of the sheet in another file.  I want to always use sheet 1 of that other file instead of the one that is name Mar 18.  I tried using Worksheets(1) but it returns an error.  

Can this be done without coding?  Because I have a boatload of these to do once, then hopefully my new workbook will be auto updated every time someone enters a new sheet in the reference workbook.

Comment: @12fretter - it would be really a good idea to ask the renewed question separately. Thus, more people would be able to answer :)

Answer (score 2):

you can create a variable that will be the new sheet:

```
Sub sheetdelet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Worksheets.Add
    .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D").Copy ws.Range("A1")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ws.Name = "Sheet1"
End With

End Sub
```